# MongoDB Aggregate on Nested Object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Any idea why this isn't returing the average (returns null)?

```
Pattern.aggregate([
      { $match: {
          name: 'asdfaddf'
      }},
      { $unwind: "$ratings" },
      { $group : { _id: "test", ratings : {  $avg : "$ratings.rating" } } }
```

My document looksl ike this

```
"ratings" : [ 
        {
            "rating" : "5",
            "userID" : "5a73ef842aed0f399ff4ee40",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a74893230eed03f1ebf3c5f")
        }, 
        {
            "rating" : "3",
            "userID" : "awefawefawfawef",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a74893230aad03f1ebf3c5e")
        }
    ],
```

Comment: That's really odd, I've even tried pushing the items in to an array and using `$avg` within a `$project` stage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like using non-numeric values, as state in the mongodb documentation these will be ignored:

> $avg ignores non-numeric values, including missing values. If all of the operands for the average are non-numeric, $avg returns null since the average of zero values is undefined.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/#non-numeric-or-missing-values

Comment: That was it.  Thanks for the eyes, Kevin.  Didn't even realize they were being stored as a string.

Comment: No worries - took me a while to realize